# Need help identifying a frame

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

Recently bought a used bike, the guy who sold it said it was an 80s/90s Schwinn steel frame. Checked it with a magnet so I'm pretty sure it's steel but I'm not sure about the model, brand, or the year. No identifiers but it seems to have a unique fork and chain guides.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are the stickers/labels on the top of the downtube ?  A close photo of them might help.

Comment: Registration stickers with local law enforcement

Comment: Could be worth contacting the local law office to see if they have other details on file.  It may just be the name/address/phone for the previous owner, which will need updating anyway so the call isn't wasted.   BTW - nice bike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, can't tell you what it is/was.

How ever some observations:

It was either a track bike from new, or the rear dropouts were replaced with track ends.  Could be a modern hipster's fixed gear sold that way, or a proper track bike.

The quill stem and threadded fork suggests 80s or 90s, but the sloping top tube makes it more of a 90s bike in design.

Seems to have a square taper bottom bracket, and it looks like a cartridge because I can't see a lockring in the photo.  This could have been a modern replacement though.

That it seems to have a rear brake bridge and obviously support for rim brakes leans away from being a real track bike where brakes are banned, though its not impossible to retrofit brakes.

Answer (score 3):

The frame looks like a 2011 to 2013 Schwinn Madison with many component changes.

The [Madison was made in 1985,](http://www.trfindley.com/flschwinn_1981_1990/1985Ltwt26.html) through 1987 as a lugged track bike.

In [2007 the Madison](http://autobus.cyclingnews.com/tech.php?id=/photos/2006/tech/news/05-12/Schwinn_Madison) was an chromoly welded fastback frame and threadless headset.
[image]
This frame is similar to yours but it does not have bottle mounts.

In 2011 the Madison went to dual bottle mounts and threaded headset with many other component changes.
[image]
Your frame looks like this one.
This style was made until 2013 - if [BikePedia](https://www.bikepedia.com/QuickBike/BikeSpecs.aspx?year=2013&brand=Schwinn%20&model=Madison) is to be believed.

**Further research**
Schwinn has sold, and is currently selling, bikes with a "track style" frame in the "Urban" category that looks similar to the bike in the original post with a variety of names. Over the years there have been a variety of components and sometimes differences in frame angles.

[image]
I was unable to find a 2013 Schwinn catalog.

Keep in mind that the [brand name "Schwinn" is owned by Dorel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinn_Bicycle_Company) Industries which owns [several other bicycle brand names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Cycle), like Cannondale, DYNO, Pacific, Roadmaster, Mongoose, Murray to name a few. It is possible for them to use the same frame with one of their other brand names for any given year.

The variety of names and years makes a single model / year identification difficult. There are many serial number decoders for older Schwinn bikes. I didn't find one for the newer bikes.

Comment: The crankset looks similar too on the 2011-2013, so that's adding some evidence. I don't think the fork on OP's bike looks quite right, like it is too tall and pitching the front of the bike up, so possibly a replacement/aftermarket fork, which is neutral evidence. I wonder if the 11 in the serial number is anything useful or just coincidence heh

Comment: Yeah the top tube angle is different, but as @Swifty points out, could be a different fork from stock.

Comment: An observation - this Schwinn has brakes and bottle cage mounts, neither of which would be used on a track bike on a track.  Perhaps this was more for fixie riders on the street use rather than real track competition ?   I still think its a great match and an excellent find.

Comment: @Criggie Good point. The Madison was a track bike when it was originally introduced "The Madison was made in 1985, through 1987 as a lugged track bike." When it was reintroduced in 2007 it became a fixed-gear/singlespeed. For greater clarity maybe I should have left off the history. I included it because the original post mentioned that he had heard the bike was an 80s or 90s bike - and I thought it was interesting.